# T-SQL DATEDIFF giving returning result 1 hours when difference is only 45 minutes

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datediff

Facing an issue with T-sql Datediff function, 
I am calculating date difference in minutes between two dates, and then in hours.

Minute is giving me correct result

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(minute,'2018-01-22 23:59:00.000','2018-01-23 00:44:00.000')
Result 45 minutes
```

But when I am trying to calculate hours it's giving me incorrect results for days that are almost over and new day begins,
So if the time parameter is  '23:59:00' and the second parameter is '00:44:00' it returns 1 hour difference when its only 45 minutes.

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(HOUR,'2018-01-22 23:59:00.000','2018-01-23 00:44:00.000')
Result 1 Hour --Incorrect
```

I am expecting this result to be zero

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(HOUR,'2018-01-22 23:59:00.000','2018-01-23 00:44:00.000')
Result 0 Hour -- This is the result expected
```

**Update:** 
Posting my Function here if anyone needs to Calculate difference between two dates in format as **Day:Hour:Minute**

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[UDF_Fedex_CalculateDeliveryOverdue] 
(
    -- Add the parameters for the function here
    @requiredDate VARCHAR(50), 
    @deliveryStamp VARCHAR(50)
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(25)
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @ResultVar VARCHAR(25)

 SET @ResultVar = ( SELECT CASE WHEN a.Days = 0 AND a.Hours = 0 THEN CAST(a.Minutes AS VARCHAR(10)) + ' Minutes'
                                WHEN a.Days = 0  THEN CAST(a.Hours AS VARCHAR(10)) + ' Hours ' + CAST(a.Minutes AS VARCHAR(10)) + ' Minutes'
                                ELSE CAST(a.Days AS VARCHAR(10)) +' Day ' + CAST(a.Hours AS VARCHAR(10)) +' Hours ' + CAST(a.Minutes AS VARCHAR(10)) + ' Minutes'

                                    END 

FROM ( SELECT DATEDIFF(hh, @requiredDate,@deliveryStamp)/24 AS 'Days'
        ,(DATEDIFF(MI, @requiredDate,@deliveryStamp)/60) - 
        (DATEDIFF(hh, @requiredDate,@deliveryStamp)/24)*24 AS 'Hours'
        ,DATEDIFF(mi, @requiredDate,@deliveryStamp) - 
        (DATEDIFF(mi, @requiredDate,@deliveryStamp)/60)*60 AS 'Minutes'
        ) a)
    -- Return the result of the function

    RETURN @ResultVar
END
```

Comment: Yes, that's how `DATEDIFF` works, and it's [nicely documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql). It counts *boundary changes*, not the actual absolute difference. There is an hour boundary change between these dates.

Comment: Wow, Never knew that Thank you, now it makes sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get value 0 you need to get the result in minutes, and convert to hours:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(minute,'2018-01-22 23:59:00.000','2018-01-23 00:44:00.000')/60
```

For more precision:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(minute,'2018-01-22 23:59:00.000','2018-01-23 00:44:00.000')/60.0
```

Comment: @Pரதீப் and that's what op said that s/he wanted as a result: `I am expecting this result to be zero`

Comment: @Lamak - My bad.. didn't read the question properly!! btw its not my downvote

Comment: Integer division is correct. 59 minutes is not 1 hour, 1 hour 1 minute is one hour as far as OP is concerned.

Comment: Well, I'm combing all that different into a string to display in the report, 
So the final Result looks like this '1 Hours 12 Minutes', So dividing by int totally works for me, I Have posted my Function above to show how it works.